# Scrape Amazon.com webpage with PHP

Tags: php, curl, domdocument

I'm trying to simply fetch the html of a remote Amazon url. I had working code, but maybe they changed something? Not sure. I've spent hours trying code samples and plugins from here and there, but nothing is working. Here's what I have right now, but of course it doesn't work either:

```php
    $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $item['URL']);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $output = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
            //echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);
        @file_put_contents($graphics_file_root.'rps/amazon/temp2.html',$output);

        $html = new DOMDocument();
        @$html->loadHTML($output);
        @file_put_contents($graphics_file_root.'rps/amazon/temp.html',$html->saveHTML());
        $temp = $html->getElementsByTagName('img');

        $html = file_get_contents($item['URL']);
        @file_put_contents($graphics_file_root.'rps/amazon/temp2.html',$html);
        $temp = $html->getElementsByTagName('img');
        echo count($temp);
        print_r($temp);
```

This doesn't work. simple_html_dom doesn't work. Nothing does that I can find.

Comment: You've not really given us much here. Do you get errors? What URL are you requesting?

Comment: Define doesn't work

Comment: BTW suppress operator `@` is not preferred in general, at least in debugging cases like yours you need all errors to be shown.

Comment: Trying to get any or all URLs from Amazon for product pages. General form is http://www.amazon.com/dp/THEPRODUCTCODE. I was getting a 301 moved error until I set follow loacation. The page that comes back looks like binary in some cases and an empty page in others.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of the code I found online was json specific and removing the json-decode fixed it:

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $item['URL']);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        $output = curl_exec($curl);
            //echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($curl);
        //file_put_contents($graphics_file_root.'rps/amazon/temp2.html',$output);

        $html = new DOMDocument();
        @$html->loadHTML($output);
        //file_put_contents($graphics_file_root.'rps/amazon/temp.html',$html->saveHTML());

        $temp = $html->getElementsByTagName('img');
```